# "This food is sweet for a meal, sour for a dessert" - the punctuation for this construction

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation, commas, antonyms

If I have to state its general form, I would write:

**... [X] + as/for/article/none + [noun 1] , [X antonym] + as/for/article/none + [noun 2] .**

*X: is any adjective*

I want to know if the comma makes the most proper punctuation to use between the two related statements which are kind of contradict each other but make, as a whole, a complete sentence.

Examples:

> This food is sweet for a meal, sour for a dessert
>
> Your method is fun for studying, boring for entertaining.
>
> Your post makes a good-quality comment, bad-quality answer.

Also, is that a well-known construction, and does it have a particular term?

Comment: You would normally need some kind of conjunction: (1) *A for B, **and** X for Y*;  (2) *A for B, **but** X for Y*; (3) *A for B, **yet** X for Y*; (4) *A for B, **although** X for Y.*

Comment: Thank you, Jason, but wouldn't even an Em dash work instead of the comma? As to direct the focus on the second part for example (since this is one of Em dash uses).

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use a dash instead of a comma. You could even put the second part inside a pair of parentheses. I think the important part is the use of a conjunction.